# How to query a running process for its parameters list? (Windows, C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, process, command-line-arguments

For a given Windows process I want to know with what command line parameters it was started. The Windows Task Manager is able to show that.

Comment: Given [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520428/how-to-query-a-running-process-for-its-parameters-list-windows-c#comment7690453_6522047) It seems like you have the wrong solution to the problem, rather than asking how to do what you want originally. If you want to stop multiple process doing the same work, you can use a mutex or semaphore to "lock" a particular section of work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you know the process ID, use [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to it (this requires elevated privilege as noted in the docs).  Then use [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get detailed process info. Use the `ProcessBasicInformation` option to get the [PEB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813706%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the process - this contains another structure pointer, through which you canget the command line.

Comment: Seems to exactly be that I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: "These APIs and data structures are subject to changes from one      Windows release to another Windows release. To maintain the compatiblity of your application, avoid using these APIs and data structures." Hm, not so easy as I hoped.

Comment: Yes, however that documentation has existed for many years and I personally doubt that's a major concern. However, you can also get the info you need using WMI if you prefer. See `CommandLine` property on Win32_Process class at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I here "WMI" the first time today. Seems not the most straight forward thing. I'll study it. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, it's very comprehensive, but a bit hokey to use since it's based on COM coding practices.  It's quite a bit easier to code to WMI using System.Management namespace in .Net Framework, if that's an option for you.  The C++/Win32 approach in my answer would be a quicker solution for now - perhaps you can wait to re-implement using WMI if you ever have to?

Comment: Yes, I'll copy the needed structs from MSDN to my code and read the PEB for now.

Answer (score 6):

### Remote thread injection:

You use remote thread injection, call `GetCommandLine()`, then IPC the result back. This might work most of the time on Windows XP, but on Windows Vista or later it doesn’t work on system and service processes. This is because `CreateRemoteThread` only works on processes in the same session ID as the caller – in Windows Vista, services and other system processes run in session 0 while user programs run in higher sessions. The best and safest way is to read a structure present in every Windows process.

### PEB structure:

The [Process Environment Block (PEB)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706(v=vs.85).aspx) is usually stored in the high regions of process memory, above `0x7ff00000`. These regions also contain Thread Environment Blocks (TEBs). The PEB address is different for almost every process, so you can’t simply use a hardcoded constant.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Winternl.h"

typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtQueryInformationProcess)(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    DWORD ProcessInformationClass,
    PVOID ProcessInformation,
    DWORD ProcessInformationLength,
    PDWORD ReturnLength
    );

PVOID GetPebAddress(HANDLE ProcessHandle)
{
    _NtQueryInformationProcess NtQueryInformationProcess =
        (_NtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;

    NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle, 0, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), NULL);

    return pbi.PebBaseAddress;
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    int pid;
    HANDLE processHandle;
    PVOID pebAddress;
    PVOID rtlUserProcParamsAddress;
    UNICODE_STRING commandLine;
    WCHAR *commandLineContents;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: getprocesscommandline [pid]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = _wtoi(argv[1]);

    if ((processHandle = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | /* required for NtQueryInformationProcess */
        PROCESS_VM_READ, /* required for ReadProcessMemory */
        FALSE, pid)) == 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open process!\n");
        return GetLastError();
    }

    pebAddress = GetPebAddress(processHandle);

    /* get the address of ProcessParameters */
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(processHandle,
            &(((_PEB*) pebAddress)->ProcessParameters),
            &rtlUserProcParamsAddress,
            sizeof(PVOID), NULL))
    {
        printf("Could not read the address of ProcessParameters!\n");
        return GetLastError();
    }

    /* read the CommandLine UNICODE_STRING structure */
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(processHandle,
        &(((_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS*) rtlUserProcParamsAddress)->CommandLine),
        &commandLine, sizeof(commandLine), NULL))
    {
        printf("Could not read CommandLine!\n");
        return GetLastError();
    }

    /* allocate memory to hold the command line */
    commandLineContents = (WCHAR *)malloc(commandLine.Length);

    /* read the command line */
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, commandLine.Buffer,
        commandLineContents, commandLine.Length, NULL))
    {
        printf("Could not read the command line string!\n");
        return GetLastError();
    }

    /* print it */
    /* the length specifier is in characters, but commandLine.Length is in bytes */
    /* a WCHAR is 2 bytes */
    printf("%.*S\n", commandLine.Length / 2, commandLineContents);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
    free(commandLineContents);

    return 0;
}
```

For more detail, Please have a look on [Get the command line of a process](https://wj32.org/wp/2009/01/24/howto-get-the-command-line-of-processes/)

### EDIT (Additional information):

First author said :

> `CreateRemoteThread` only works on processes in the same session ID as
>   the caller – in Windows Vista, services and other system processes run
>   in session 0 while user programs run in higher sessions. The best and safest way is to read a structure present in every Windows process.

It is the same thing with [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), you can't open a process which is a service or a process opened by *SYSTEM* or *LOCAL SERVICE* or *NETWORK SERVICE*, if you are running your program by a user (even administrator).

If your program is a service, it is probably already running by *local system account*, so no problem.
But if not, a solution is to launch it with [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx):

> 1. Download [PSEXEC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and unzip to some folder.
> 2. Open an elevated CMD prompt as an administrator.
> 3. Navigate to the folder where you unzipped PSEXEC.EXE
> 4. Run: `PSEXEC -i -s -d CMD`
> 5. You will have a new CMD prompt open.
> 6. Type the following in the new CMD prompt to prove who you are: `WHOAMI`

You should see that you are *SYSTEM*, now you can launch your program and see the command line for all processes.

Answer (score 4):

You can't ***reliably*** get that information. There are various tricks to try and retrieve it, but there's no guarantee that the target process hasn't already mangled that section of memory. Raymond Chen discussed this awhile back on [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923).

Comment: Thank you, too. It's an interesting link. Since I only want to check the command line of our own processes (which doesn't intentionally change it), I should be fine. The reason I need the command line is that I'm writing a service that makes sure, that a set of processes in a defined configuration are running or not at some point in time. To verify that I compare path-to-exe-file and command line of the processes.

Comment: @beutelfuchs: A mutex or semaphore will be better in that case.

Comment: The linked page has moved: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923

Comment: If you want to get the command line of current process, [`GetCommandLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) (linking the ANSI version, for Unicode/"multibyte"/"wide-char" see `GetCommandLineW` as per convention) is the procedure you want.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could [inject a dll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) into the foreign process address space and then call [**GetCommandLine**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Definitely a solution but in my case more complicated compared to Steves approach. Because I would have to use IPC to get the "stolen" command line back to my querying process.