# Process information using Python, NOT using wmi, psutil, tasklist

Tags: python, command-line, process, wmi

I'm writing a Python script that gets information on processes (PID, Command Line, etc.) running on a PC.

On my Windows 7 PC I can use 'wmic' and use the output from that:

*output = subprocess.Popen(['wmic process get creationdate,commandline,processid'],   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]*

Example of the info I can get from this output:

*PROCESS   PID     START TIME                      COMMAND:
blah.exe       1234   Thu Jun 06 15:33:40 2013    C:\blah\blah.exe -a -b blah.txt*

This gives me all the info I need... HOWEVER not all machines will let me use 'wmic' as I'm not an Administrator.

I can use 'tasklist', but it doesn't give me the 'commandline' info that wmic does.

I can't use 'psutils' (or the 'wmi' module), as it's not installed on any of the PCs I need it to work on, and I don't want to have to get admin install modules on all these PCs

Any ideas on how I can get the above process information using standard Python 2.6?

Thanks in advance,
Nick

PYTHON 2.6 on Windows XP/7

=====================================================================

EDIT (12 June 2013):

I'm trying to do as suggested below, but having trouble... I've put the psutil directory (psutil-0.7.1) in the same directory as my script and added the following to my script:

path = '.\psutil-0.7.1'

sys.path.append(path)

import psutil

I now get the below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\nickw\Desktop\ProcessMonitor\ProcessMonitor_MODPS2.py", line 21, in <module>

    import psutil

  File ".\psutil-0.7.1\psutil\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>

    import psutil._psmswindows as _psplatform

  File ".\psutil-0.7.1\psutil\_psmswindows.py", line 15, in <module>

     import _psutil_mswindows

ImportError: No module named _psutil_mswindows
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: psutils don't require admin rights - just place them anywhere, e.g. besides your program.

Comment: The same goes for `wmi` module (it requires `pywin32` though).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm having trouble doing that - see above...

Comment: Actually, I didn't know about a _python module_ called "psutil", I meant the sysinternals console utilities. The error says the `psutil` module requires another one, `_psutil_mswindows`. It's probably a DLL and the former module probably acts as a proxy for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique to retrieve a process's command line is somewhat hacky but was included into WMI since XP. Basically, it's reading another process's memory. See e.g. [Getting another process command line in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530565/getting-another-process-command-line-in-windows) and links from there for details.

So, you either

- re-implement it yourself by hand, with `ctypes` or whatever, like the link above says, or
- somehow, utilize existing modules that will do that for you. There's [`zipimport`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) to make this easier for multiple files and [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create whole environments anywhere on the filesystem, the latter likely being an overkill.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Although I didn't use the solution you suggested, it made me realise that the 'very simple solution' that I hoped for wasn't there! So... I've managed to sort out using the WMI python module, which seems to work OK. Thanks again :-)

Comment: What I've actually done is installed the [WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI) python module on my PC and used it in my script. So that I don't have to install WMI on all the PCs I want to run it on, I've create a .exe from the .py script using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). Seems to work OK so far...