# Modifying command line arguments for GetCommandLine()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to modify command line arguments of my executable so that GetCommandLine() will return the string I set. Since I want to modify the command line value before anyone, I have changed my entry point to testme() function via /ENTRY switch and also set /NODEFAULTLIB option in order to exclude CRT. Using the following code why can I change the string buffer pointer by CommandLine but cannot allocate a completely new buffer?

The code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *PFN_NtQueryInformationProcess)(
    IN HANDLE               ProcessHandle,
    IN PROCESSINFOCLASS       ProcessInformationClass,
    IN PVOID                ProcessInformation,
    IN ULONG                ProcessInformationLength,
    _Out_opt_  PULONG ReturnLength );

int testme()
{
   // Get PEB block address

   PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
   ULONG result;

   PFN_NtQueryInformationProcess pfnQueryProcess = 
    (PFN_NtQueryInformationProcess) GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("ntdll"),
        "NtQueryInformationProcess");

  pfnQueryProcess(GetCurrentProcessId(),
    ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &result);

  // Modify ProcessParameters->CommandLine

  // This works
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Buffer[0] = L'a';
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Buffer[1] = L' ';
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Buffer[2] = L'b';
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Buffer[3] = L'\0';
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Length = 6;

  // This does not work  

  UNICODE_STRING cmdLine;

  wchar_t wszNewCmdLine[] = L"x y\0";

  cmdLine.Buffer = (wchar_t*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, sizeof(wchar_t)*pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.MaximumLength);
  cmdLine.MaximumLength = pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.MaximumLength;
  cmdLine.Length = sizeof(wszNewCmdLine) - sizeof(L'\0');

  //Copy buffer 
  for(int i=0; i<cmdLine.Length; ++i)
      cmdLine.Buffer[i] = wszNewCmdLine[i];

  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Buffer = cmdLine.Buffer;
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Length = cmdLine.Length;
  pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.MaximumLength = cmdLine.MaximumLength;

  // Now testing, pCmdLine returned is "a b", not "x y".
  wchar_t *pCmdLine = GetCommandLine();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: NtQueryInformationProcess() takes a process handle, not a PID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `GetCommandLineW` doesn't return the command line from the PEB. In the `BaseDllInitialize` routine a copy is made of the PEB command line structure, and from then on  this copy is used by `GetCommandLineW`. You would need to locate this copy in memory in order to modify it, which seems quite difficult and also dangerous/unreliable.

You could look at an API hook like Detours, but an easier solution might just be to launch your executable with your desired command line in the first place. You could test when it starts up if the command line is right and if not have it spawn another copy of itself with the desired command line.

Comment: This is also my conclusion, yet your answer came first. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of trial and error I come up with following. I wrote a C executable that only links with `kernel32.lib` and does not link `CRT`. In the `exe`, I do `EAT` patching of `GetCommandLineX` functions in `kernel32.dll`. Then I load another of my dll (test.dll) which  needs `GetCommandLineX` method as part of its functions. Since `kernel32` is patched, loader fills the import table of the test.dll with the patched function pointers. In the end, methods in the test.dll calls my version of GetCommandLineX, which I can easily change their implementation.