# C++ iterate processes and find out command line args of each process

Tags: c++, process, module, arguments, psapi

I have the following problem to solve (VS2012, C++)
I have to find out if a specific HTA app is running from my exe. For that, I have to find the process mshta and check if it has correct arguments (should have been started as "mshta somehta.hta"). My first attempt was to iterate over the processes/modules, which I can do now. I see mshta listed and its PID. But, I did not find the way to get the info, how it was started. Is there a way to do it?

```
ProcessExists(wchar_t* processName)
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return false;
    }


    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
        }
    }

    return false;

 }
 void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                               PROCESS_VM_READ,
                               FALSE, processID );

    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
         &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                           sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );


        }
    }

    // Print the process name and identifier.

    dprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u) %s %s\n"), szProcessName, processID );

   // Release the handle to the process.

   CloseHandle( hProcess );
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530565/getting-another-process-command-line-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up to use the solution proposed here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess