# Can I read with what arguments a process was called?

Tags: c++, process, command-line-arguments

I can start a process from an executable with arguments via a C++ program like this:

```
system("file.exe arguments")
```

Given a specific process (and the process that called this process (*possibly via `system()`*), if required), is there any way to find out the argument it has been called with (or, in other words, *the way* it has been called)?

Comment: I dont get it, you are starting yourself *file.exe* and passing *arguments* as parameter, what you need to know? what *arguments* is?

Comment: Well, *another* process started *even another process* with **arguments**, and I want to find out the **arguments** the *even another process* was called with.

Comment: C++ has no notion of process. You need to refer to your OS API.

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows -- did you have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530565/getting-another-process-command-line-in-windows ?

Comment: @devRicher your explanation is still not very clear. You probably need to rephrase your question and give an example.

Comment: @skalarproduktraum First question perfectly explains my situation, but I'm looking on how to implement that in C++.

Comment: @devRicher: Well, then the second question gives some ideas how to achieve that.