# Why arguments of ProcessStartInfo is empty?

Tags: windows, powershell

When I tried to get command line arguments of a executable, I tried inspect the `ProcessStartInfo` structure returned by `Get-Process`, but the argument field is empty no matter what:

```
PS C:\> ps notepad

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    272      15     3484      19888       0.39  33696   1 notepad

PS C:\> $(ps notepad).StartInfo

Verb                    :
Arguments               :
CreateNoWindow          : False
EnvironmentVariables    : {ConEmuBaseDir, ConEmuConfig, ConEmuArgs,    PROCESSOR_REVISION...}
Environment             : {[ConEmuBaseDir, C:\Users\fluter\Tools\ConEmu.Core.17.1.18.0\Tools\ConEmu], [ConEmuConfig, ], [ConEmuArgs, ], [PROCESSOR_REVISION, 4501]...}
RedirectStandardInput   : False
RedirectStandardOutput  : False
RedirectStandardError   : False
StandardErrorEncoding   :
StandardOutputEncoding  :
UseShellExecute         : True
Verbs                   : {}
UserName                :
Password                :
PasswordInClearText     :
Domain                  :
LoadUserProfile         : False
FileName                :
WorkingDirectory        :
ErrorDialog             : False
ErrorDialogParentHandle : 0
WindowStyle             : Normal
```

But as expected, the `procexp` utility in sysinternals suite can get full command line:

[image]

Also, as comments pointed out, using win32 wmi object interface can get it. However, why is this feature missing from powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Command Line info for a process in PowerShell or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563411/how-to-get-command-line-info-for-a-process-in-powershell-or-c-sharp)

Comment: Do you know why arguments or startinfo is empty?

Comment: Sorry, no. Must have had a reason why MicroSoft baught Sysinternals. Task-Manager grew better, but I'm still using ProcExp.

Comment: a) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522047/478656 -
 you cannot reliably get it. and b) if you want to anyway,  https://superuser.com/a/519802/67909 and https://serverfault.com/q/696460/57144

Comment: The documentation for the [Process.StartInfo property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that it's the information with which to start the process. But you didn't start the process, so the StartInfo doesn't mean anything. The confusion is that the `Process` class is used for two different things. One is for starting a new process. The other is for getting information about existing processes. Only the first cases uses `StartInfo`.

Comment: Oh! that explains it all, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand, but @LotPing point the answer :

```
$proc = Get-Process notepad
$pInfos = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$($proc.MainModule.ModuleName)'" 
$pInfos.CommandLine
```

`CommandLine` gives you the same information as ProcessXP

---

You will find something in `startinfo` when this object is used to start the process :

```
$startInfo = New-Object Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.Filename = "notepad"
$startInfo.Arguments = "toto.txt"
$startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$Proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startInfo)
```

It exists many way to start a process this one use an object `Process` that encapsulate the Win32 `CreateProcess`. As far as I understand when the command line is used, you will not find data in startinfo, when the process is started programaticaly it can append.

Comment: My question was more like why This information is not in `ProcessStartupInfo`? using WMI is only last resort.

Comment: I Explain it in my answer.