# Get ProcessID from binary path (command line statement) in C++

Tags: c++, windows, process

I need to find a specific svchost process. The only thing I have is the command line statement (binary path): `c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -s Themes`.
How can I get the processID from that?

Comment: You can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). Just mouse over the various `svchost.exe` processes until you find the `netsvcs` one.

Comment: What does C++ have to do with it?

Comment: I wanted a way to do that in c++ (kinda obvious isnt it?)

Comment: First you need to enumerate all processes and then use answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520428/how-to-query-a-running-process-for-its-parameters-list-windows-c to extract start-up parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course not possible direct get process ID from command line. possible visa versa - get process command line from process ID. so possible enumerate all processes and query it command lines. and compare it with your string (*and interesting from where you "have is the command line statement" ? it hard coded ?*)

begin from *WINBLUE* (win 8.1) exist special `PROCESSINFOCLASS` - `ProcessCommandLineInformation` (look in `<ntddk.h>` from 8.1 or 10 wdk). with this we can get process Command Line as unicode string. this will be work for both native and wow64 processes. also process handle heed have only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access. if we have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` we can open all processes with this. and if we have not - all, except protected processes. so code for *WINBLUE* + will be:

```
volatile UCHAR guz;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa) };

// since WINBLUE (8.1)
NTSTATUS GetProcessCommandLine8(HANDLE UniqueProcess, PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    CLIENT_ID cid = { UniqueProcess };

    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &zoa, &cid);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PUNICODE_STRING CmdLine;
        };

        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 512;

        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

            if (0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessCommandLineInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
            {
                status = RtlDuplicateUnicodeString(RTL_DUPLICATE_UNICODE_STRING_NULL_TERMINATE, CmdLine, CommandLine);
                break;
            }

        } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

        NtClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}
```

but for old systems all become more complex. need first query `ProcessBasicInformation` for get process *PEB* address , than get address of `ProcessParameters` (`RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`) from *PEB*. and finally read from it `CommandLine` (`UNICODE_STRING`). but for this need at first open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ` access. as result we fail open protected processes, even if we have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE`, and if we not have it - we in general can open processes from own logon session (so fail for all system processes, for all elevated processes). at second need write different code for native and wow64 case: if our code is 32bit - need check are we wow64 process, if yes - query for `NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64` and `NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64` first, and only then can begin query process cmd line.

code for native process:

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessCommandLineOldNative(HANDLE UniqueProcess, PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    CLIENT_ID cid = { UniqueProcess };

    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, &zoa, &cid);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
        UNICODE_STRING CmdLine;
        union {
            _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS * ProcessParameters;
            PVOID buf;
            PWSTR psz;
        };
        if (
            0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, &((_PEB*)pbi.PebBaseAddress)->ProcessParameters, &ProcessParameters, sizeof(ProcessParameters), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, &ProcessParameters->CommandLine, &CmdLine, sizeof(CmdLine), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, CmdLine.Buffer, buf = alloca(CmdLine.Length), CmdLine.Length, 0))
            )
        {
            CmdLine.Buffer = psz;
            status = RtlDuplicateUnicodeString(RTL_DUPLICATE_UNICODE_STRING_NULL_TERMINATE, &CmdLine, CommandLine);
        }

        NtClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}
```

for wow64 process:

```
#ifndef _WIN64

extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllimport) 
    NTSTATUS NTAPI NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64 (
        HANDLE ProcessHandle,
        PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
        PVOID ProcessInformation,
        ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
        PULONG ReturnLength
        );

    __declspec(dllimport) 
    NTSTATUS NTAPI NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64(
        HANDLE ProcessHandle,
        UINT64 BaseAddress,
        PVOID Buffer,
        ULONG64 Size,
        PULONG64 NumberOfBytesRead
        );

    PVOID __imp_NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64, __imp_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64;
}

#ifdef _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:__imp__NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64@28=___imp_NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64")
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:__imp__NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64@20=___imp_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64")
#endif

NTSTATUS GetProcessCommandLineOldWow(HANDLE UniqueProcess, PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine)
{
    struct PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_64 {
        NTSTATUS ExitStatus;
        UINT64 PebBaseAddress;
        UINT64 AffinityMask;
        KPRIORITY BasePriority;
        UINT64 UniqueProcessId;
        UINT64 InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
    };

    struct PEB_64
    {
        UCHAR InheritedAddressSpace;
        UCHAR ReadImageFileExecOptions;
        UCHAR BeingDebugged;
        UCHAR SpareBool;
        UINT64 Mutant;
        UINT64 ImageBaseAddress;
        UINT64 Ldr;
        UINT64 ProcessParameters;
    };

    struct UNICODE_STRING_64 {
        USHORT Length;
        USHORT MaximumLength;
        UINT64 Buffer;
    };

    struct CURDIR_64 {
        UNICODE_STRING_64 DosPath;
        UINT64 Handle;
    };

    struct RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS_64 {
        ULONG MaximumLength;
        ULONG Length;
        ULONG Flags;
        ULONG DebugFlags;
        UINT64 ConsoleHandle;
        ULONG ConsoleFlags;
        UINT64 StandardInput;
        UINT64 StandardOutput;
        UINT64 StandardError;
        CURDIR_64 CurrentDirectory;
        UNICODE_STRING_64 DllPath;
        UNICODE_STRING_64 ImagePathName;
        UNICODE_STRING_64 CommandLine;
        /*...*/
    };

    HANDLE hProcess;
    CLIENT_ID cid = { UniqueProcess };

    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, &zoa, &cid);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_64 pbi;
        UNICODE_STRING_64 CmdLine;
        UNICODE_STRING cl;
        UINT64 ProcessParameters;

        if (
            0 <= (status = NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64(hProcess, pbi.PebBaseAddress + FIELD_OFFSET(PEB_64, ProcessParameters), &ProcessParameters, sizeof(ProcessParameters), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64(hProcess, ProcessParameters + FIELD_OFFSET(RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS_64, CommandLine), &CmdLine, sizeof(CmdLine), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64(hProcess, CmdLine.Buffer, cl.Buffer = (PWSTR)alloca(CmdLine.Length), CmdLine.Length, 0))
            )
        {
            cl.Length = CmdLine.Length, cl.MaximumLength = CmdLine.MaximumLength;
            status = RtlDuplicateUnicodeString(RTL_DUPLICATE_UNICODE_STRING_NULL_TERMINATE, &cl, CommandLine);
        }

        NtClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS GetProcessCommandLineFail(HANDLE , PUNICODE_STRING )
{
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

#endif//_WIN64
```

and finally at begin we need determinate windows version and (if version < 8.1) wow64 and once select procedure for get process cmdline:

```
NTSTATUS (*GetProcessCommandLine)(HANDLE UniqueProcess, PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine);

WORD gosVersion;

void InitQueryCmdLine()
{
    BOOLEAN b;
    RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);

    ULONG dwMajorVersion, dwMinorVersion;
    RtlGetNtVersionNumbers(&dwMajorVersion, &dwMinorVersion, 0);
    gosVersion = MAKEWORD(dwMinorVersion, dwMajorVersion);

    if (gosVersion < _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE)
    {
#ifdef _WIN64
        GetProcessCommandLine = GetProcessCommandLineOldNative;
#else
        GetProcessCommandLine = GetProcessCommandLineFail;

        PVOID wow64peb;
        if (0 <= NtQueryInformationProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessWow64Information, &wow64peb, sizeof(wow64peb), 0))
        {
            if (wow64peb)
            {
                if (HMODULE hmod = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"))
                {
                    if ((__imp_NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64 = GetProcAddress(hmod, "NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64")) &&
                        (__imp_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64 = GetProcAddress(hmod, "NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64")))
                    {
                        GetProcessCommandLine = GetProcessCommandLineOldWow;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                GetProcessCommandLine = GetProcessCommandLineOldNative;
            }
        }
#endif
    }
    else
    {
        GetProcessCommandLine = GetProcessCommandLine8;
    }
}
```

after this we can enumerate processes and query command line for every process.

```
void DumpCmdLines()
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(0x1000 + rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
            do 
            {
                pb += NextEntryOffset;

                if (HANDLE UniqueProcessId = pspi->UniqueProcessId)
                {
                    UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;
                    status = GetProcessCommandLine(UniqueProcessId, &CommandLine);
                    if (0 > status)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%p <%wZ> error=%x\n", UniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName, status);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%p <%wZ> <%wZ>\n", UniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName, &CommandLine);
                        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&CommandLine);
                    }
                }

            } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

            break;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
}
```

and possible result (win10)

```
00000004 <System> error=c0000225
0000015C <smss.exe> <\SystemRoot\System32\smss.exe>
000001D4 <csrss.exe> <%SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=basesrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=sxssrv,4 ProfileControl=Off MaxRequestThreads=16>
00000234 <wininit.exe> <wininit.exe>
0000023C <csrss.exe> <%SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=basesrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=sxssrv,4 ProfileControl=Off MaxRequestThreads=16>
00000294 <winlogon.exe> <winlogon.exe>
000002C0 <services.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\services.exe>
000002C8 <lsass.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe>
0000032C <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch>
0000036C <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS>
000003D8 <dwm.exe> <"dwm.exe">
00000060 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs>
00000144 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted>
00000300 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted>
00000408 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork>
0000044C <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalService>
00000518 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted>
00000550 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted>
00000564 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService>
00000670 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k imgsvc>
00000688 <svchost.exe> <C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k appmodel>
00000698 <dasHost.exe> <dashost.exe {d48bf429-3cb0-4538-8bc9147caa7c9ef1}>
00000AE4 <sihost.exe> <sihost.exe>
00000B00 <taskhostw.exe> <taskhostw.exe {222A245B-E637-4AE9-A93F-A59CA119A75E}>
00000A2C <explorer.exe> <C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE>
00000A64 <RuntimeBroker.exe> <C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe -Embedding>
00000C2C <ShellExperienceHost.exe> <"C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXtk181tbxbce2qsex02s8tw7hfxa9xb3t.mca>
00000C84 <SearchUI.exe> <"C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe" -ServerName:CortanaUI.AppXa50dqqa5gqv4a428c9y1jjw7m3btvepj.mca>
00000E38 <InstallAgent.exe> <C:\Windows\System32\InstallAgent.exe -Embedding>
00000E8C <InstallAgentUserBroker.exe> <C:\Windows\System32\InstallAgentUserBroker.exe -Embedding>
0000089C <WUDFHost.exe> <"C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe" -HostGUID:{193a1820-d9ac-4997-8c55-be817523f6aa} -IoEventPortName:HostProcess-cfc003bd-dfb8-4921-bf6c-d6392e543bad -SystemEventPortName:HostProcess-91a86d23-34aa-4a16-9d90-8417b8b3531f -IoCancelEventPortName:HostProcess-126930e6-a2d4-492d-87d4-837dcc9de0f1 -NonStateChangingEventPortName:HostProcess-13646e1e-5d48-479e-a391-22f24bfd3b7c -ServiceSID:S-1-5-80-2652678385-582572993-1835434367-1344795993-749280709 -LifetimeId:be105ab5-26a2-45ef-b565-1b2
0000052C <fontdrvhost.exe> <"fontdrvhost.exe">
```