# How to get the command line arguments from a given process pid?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get the command line arguments passed when a process is created, for example:

open cmd and type `notepad.exe --abc`

I would like to retrieve the information: `notepad.exe  --abc` or just `--abc`.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082113), the third answer is not compiling, i tried to write something based on the second.

I'm getting an access violation exception at `peb.ProcessParameters->CommandLine;`

Compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

std::wstring GetProcCommandLine(DWORD pid)
{
    std::wstring commandLine;

    // Open a handle to the process
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if (process != NULL)
    {
        // Get the address of the PEB
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
        if (NtQueryInformationProcess(process, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), NULL) == 0) // 0: STATUS_SUCCESS
        {
            // Get the address of the process parameters in the PEB
            PEB peb;
            ZeroMemory(&peb, sizeof(peb));
            if (ReadProcessMemory(process, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), NULL))
            {
                // Get the command line arguments from the process parameters
                UNICODE_STRING commandLineArgs = peb.ProcessParameters->CommandLine;
                WCHAR* buffer = new WCHAR[commandLineArgs.Length + 1];
                ZeroMemory(buffer, (commandLineArgs.Length + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
                if (ReadProcessMemory(process, commandLineArgs.Buffer, buffer, commandLineArgs.Length, NULL))
                {
                    std::wstring wideCommandLine(buffer, commandLineArgs.Length / sizeof(WCHAR));
                    commandLine = wideCommandLine;
                }
                delete[] buffer;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(process);
    }

    return commandLine;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring commandLine = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe arg1 arg2 arg3";
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, &commandLine[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        std::cout << "failed in creating the process.";

    std::wstring procCommandLine = GetProcCommandLine(pi.dwProcessId);
}
```

Comment: Did you also note the accepted answer is that it can't _reliably_ be done? And does notepad actually run when given 3 meaningless arguments or does it err out?

Comment: "And does notepad actually run when given 3 meaningless arguments or does it err out?" Yes it does run, and obviously these arguments are just to test the function.

Comment: ProcessParameters is a pointer. You need to ReadProcessMemory() it into a local copy in your process.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need another `ReadProcessMemory` to get the `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` pointed to by `peb.ProcessParameters`.  You read that pointer out of the other process's memory, so it points to memory in the other process's address space.

Comment: Raymond Chen blogged about this topic: [How do I get the command line of another process?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923)

Comment: @Luke i didnt get it

Comment: begin from win8 exist *ProcessCommandLineInformation* for *NtQueryInformationProcess* for win7 - simply need more accurate coding

Comment: @RbMm more accurately, from Windows 8.1 ([according to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894614/65863))

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, you correct, from 8.1 exactly. but pure 8 very rare now

Comment: `&peb, sizeof(peb)` - not need read all peb. we need only read one field from it `&reinterpret_cast<PEB*>(pbi.PebBaseAddress)->ProcessParameters, &ProcessParameters` than we can not direct access `ProcessParameters` pointer - it in another context. again need read `&ProcessParameters->CommandLine, &CmdLine` and finally allocate `CmdLine.Length + sizeof(WCHAR)` and read from `CmdLine.Buffer` - so must be **3** read memory

Comment: @RbMm "again need read &ProcessParameters->CommandLine, &CmdLine" i didnt understand this part, i also look at the link Remy sent, but i got a lot of undefined variables.

Comment: @Daniel -  *i didnt understand this part* - why so simply thing is unclear ? or my english too bad ? *but i got a lot of undefined variables.* - and so what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, you are trying to read from invalid memory, which is why your code is crashing with an Access Violation.

You are copying the other process's `PEB` structure into your own memory, which is fine. However, that `PEB` contains pointers that are still pointing within the other process's memory, not in your own memory.

So, you need to copy the `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` structure which `peb.ProcessParameters` is pointing at into your own memory before you can then copy its `CommandLine` data into your memory, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

std::wstring GetProcCommandLine(DWORD pid)
{
    std::wstring commandLine;

    // Open a handle to the process
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if (process == NULL)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to open the process, error: " << err << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the address of the PEB
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi = {};
        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(process, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), NULL);
        if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cerr << "failed to query the process, error: " << status << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the address of the process parameters in the PEB
            PEB peb = {};
            if (!ReadProcessMemory(process, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), NULL))
            {
                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                std::cerr << "failed to read the process PEB, error: " << err << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the command line arguments from the process parameters
                RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS params = {};
                if (!ReadProcessMemory(process, peb.ProcessParameters, &params, sizeof(params), NULL))
                {
                    DWORD err = GetLastError();
                    std::cerr << "failed to read the process params, error: " << err << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    UNICODE_STRING &commandLineArgs = params.CommandLine;
                    std::vector<WCHAR> buffer(commandLineArgs.Length / sizeof(WCHAR));
                    if (!ReadProcessMemory(process, commandLineArgs.Buffer, buffer.data(), commandLineArgs.Length, NULL))
                    {
                        DWORD err = GetLastError();
                        std::cerr << "failed to read the process command line, error: " << err << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commandLine.assign(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(process);
    }

    return commandLine;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring commandLine = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe arg1 arg2 arg3";

    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

    if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, &commandLine[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to create the process, error: " << err << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wstring procCommandLine = GetProcCommandLine(pi.dwProcessId);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        if (!procCommandLine.empty())
            std::wcout << L"Command Line: " << procCommandLine << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, on Windows 8.1 and later, you can use `NtQueryInformationProcess()` with the (undocumented!) `ProcessCommandLineInformation` option instead, then you won't need to use `ReadProcessMemory()` at all, eg:

```
std::wstring GetProcCommandLine(DWORD pid)
{
    std::wstring commandLine;

    // Open a handle to the process
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (process == NULL)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to open the process, error: " << err << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the size of the command line arguments from the process
        ULONG size = 0;
        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessCommandLineInformation, NULL, 0, &size);
        if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            std::cerr << "failed to query the process command line, error: " << status << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the command line arguments from the process
            std::vector<BYTE> buffer(size);
            status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessCommandLineInformation, buffer.data(), size, NULL);
            if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                std::cerr << "failed to read the process command line, error: " << status << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                PUNICODE_STRING commandLineArgs = reinterpret_cast<PUNICODE_STRING>(buffer.data());
                commandLine.assign(commandLineArgs->Buffer, commandLineArgs->Length / sizeof(WCHAR));
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(process);
    }

    return commandLine;
}
```

Comment: we can, but not need read ALL `PEB`, and ALL `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`. form `PEB` we need only read `ProcessParameters` (4/8 bytes) and from `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` we need read only `CommandLine`

Comment: Thank you all, as most of this api are undoc, while searching about i found that is also possible to get the `window title` from it, the struct `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` parameters: https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.html , could you also point how to get it?

Comment: @RbMm "*not need read ALL `PEB`, and ALL `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`*" - I'm aware of that, I was trying to keep things simpler for the OP without involving pointer arithmetic and such. What you are suggesting is just an optimization.

Comment: yes, this is optimization. but not need any pointer arithmetic , if you look on my code. what is more simply.. this is question, depend. in any case for such code need deep understand what we doing, not just copy-paste not own solution

Comment: What include necessary to use the `ProcessCommandLineInformation` version, `ProcessCommandLineInformation` is undefined.

Comment: @Daniel It is undocumented, and AFAIK not defined anywhere in the API.  Its numeric value is `60`.

Comment: Thank you! do you know about the window title i asked before?

Comment: @Daniel Simply use the same code that reads in the `CommandLine` field of `peb.ProcessParameters`, but using the `WindowTitle` field instead. You just need a fuller  definition of `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` that includes the `WindowTitle` field. Microsoft doesn't provide that, but you can get that from any number of reverse-engineering websites and copy it into your code

Comment: *ProcessCommandLineInformation*  defined in *ntddk.h*

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> PEB peb;
> ReadProcessMemory(process, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), NULL)
> ```

this is not efficient - we not need read all PEB ( and we anyway dont know it full size and lyout - it changed in every new windows version). we need only read single member from it - `ProcessParameters`

so need code like

```
RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS * ProcessParameters;

ReadProcessMemory(process, 
    &reinterpret_cast<PEB*>(pbi.PebBaseAddress)->ProcessParameters, 
    &ProcessParameters, sizeof(ProcessParameters), NULL);
```

then

> ```
> UNICODE_STRING commandLineArgs = peb.ProcessParameters->CommandLine;
> ```

this is of course error
`peb.ProcessParameters` - pointer in target process, we can not direct access this address in another process

so we need

```
UNICODE_STRING CmdLine;
ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, 
            &ProcessParameters->CommandLine, &CmdLine, sizeof(CmdLine), 0);
```

complete code is

```
NTSTATUS ShowCmdLine_Old(HANDLE UniqueProcess)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    CLIENT_ID cid = { UniqueProcess };
    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, &zoa, &cid);
    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
        UNICODE_STRING CmdLine;
        union {
            _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS * ProcessParameters;
            PVOID buf;
            PWSTR psz;
        };

        if (0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, 
            &reinterpret_cast<_PEB*>(pbi.PebBaseAddress)->ProcessParameters, 
            &ProcessParameters, sizeof(ProcessParameters), 0)) &&
            0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, 
            &ProcessParameters->CommandLine, &CmdLine, sizeof(CmdLine), 0)))
        {
            if (buf = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, CmdLine.Length + sizeof(WCHAR)))
            {
                if (0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, CmdLine.Buffer, buf, CmdLine.Length, 0)))
                {
                    *(PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(buf, CmdLine.Length) = 0;
                    CmdLine.Buffer = psz;
                    DbgPrint("\"%wZ\"\n", &CmdLine);
                }
                LocalFree(buf);
            }
        }

        NtClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}
```

begin from win8.1 we can use `ProcessCommandLineInformation` and all became more simply. also need only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access

```
// since WINBLUE (8.1)

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa) };

NTSTATUS ShowCmdLine_8_1(HANDLE UniqueProcess)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    CLIENT_ID cid = { UniqueProcess };

    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &zoa, &cid);

    if (0 <= status)
    {

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PUNICODE_STRING CmdLine;
        };

        ULONG cb = 0x100;

        do 
        {
            status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;

            if (buf = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cb))
            {
                if (0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessCommandLineInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
                {
                    DbgPrint("\"%wZ\"\n", CmdLine);
                }

                LocalFree(buf);
            }

        } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

        NtClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}
```

and select hich version use (once)

```
NTSTATUS (*ShowCmdLine)(HANDLE UniqueProcess);

union NT_OS_VER 
{
    ULONG FullVersion;
    struct  
    {
        USHORT Build;
        union {
            USHORT Version;
            struct  
            {
                UCHAR Minor;
                UCHAR Major;
            };
        };
    };

    NT_OS_VER()
    {
        ULONG M, m, b;
        RtlGetNtVersionNumbers(&M, &m, &b);
        Build = (USHORT)b;
        Minor = (UCHAR)m;
        Major = (UCHAR)M;
    }
};

void InitShowCmdLine()
{
    NT_OS_VER nt_ver;

    ShowCmdLine = nt_ver.Version < _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE ? ShowCmdLine_Old : ShowCmdLine_8_1;
}
```