# How to query a running thread for its parameters list? (Windows, Rust/C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, rust, wmi

This is in continuation of [How to query a running process for its parameters list? (Windows, C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520428/).

I am currently using WMI to get the arguments a process was launched with, but WMI does not contain the same information for a thread.

For a given Windows thread, I want to know what parameters it was started with.

Comment: Do not confuse threads with processes. Also do not use OS specific threads but [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). You start a thread with a function which can have arguments/parameters just like any other functions. So what is your real question/problem? Maybe you can explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can't use WMI for thread arguments, because threads don't have command-line arguments. A thread function is just a normal function like any other.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I am trying to monitor thread and process creation and what all it holds.

Comment: I don't imagine they're stored anywhere, you'd have to attach a debugger and examine the call stack

Comment: How do you want to monitor things? Do you want to monitor threads (processes) you created yourself or threads (processes) created by others?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I want to monitor real time process and thread creation. So threads created b others too.

Comment: Then don't write your own code, use processexplorer as described here: https://superuser.com/questions/462969/how-can-i-view-the-active-threads-of-a-running-program

Comment: @PepijnKramer It is a part of another larger program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) function allows a client to pass a single value. Its interpretation is at the discretion of the thread routine. The only requirement being that the value is pointer-sized. No other assumptions about its type are being made, so even if you somehow managed to get a hold of the value, you wouldn't know how to interpret it.

This is in contrast to the command line arguments passed into a process, that differ in two significant ways:

- They have a well-known type, so anyone knows how to interpret them.
- They are stored by the OS in a special place, so anyone can get access at any time.

The latter, in particular, isn't true for a thread's argument(s): The caller of `CreateThread` and the thread routine privately coordinate how long the value needs to live. And when that time is over, the value is gone, forever.

Comment: Is there any way that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext be exploited to get those arguments?

Comment: @sn99 What for? You don't know what the data means, so why even ask for it? For sake of argument, let's assume for a minute that you can, and you got yourself a fine value of `42`. Now what? How are you going to know whether that value represents a timeout in milliseconds, a width in logical pixels, a window handle, or a file descriptor? There's **nothing** meaningful you can do with that value.

Comment: Zamn, so best to consider this a dead end I presume.